# Return JSON as string with Java

Tags: java, json

I have always used XML for returning data from my servlets and i have decided to have a go with JSON.Simple.

I currently have;

```
    public JSONObject loadDetails() throws IOException {


    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    list.add(new Car("car1",3,4,3,2,4,5));
    list.add(new Car("car2",3,4,3,2,4,5));

    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();

    list.writeJSONString(out);

     System.out.println(out.toString());

    return null;
}
```

I am trying to store some car details, however when i try and print i just get the object names rather than the correct JSON value. My car class implements JSONStreamAware eg;

```
 public void writeJSONString (Writer out) throws IOException{
    LinkedHashMap obj = new LinkedHashMap();
    obj.put("carname", carname);
    obj.put("engine", engine);

    JSONValue.writeJSONString(obj, out);
}
```

Have i missed something here?

Comment: try http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ a good way to work with json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I know that this is not what you are explicitly asking for but I will definitely recommend using Gson for json parsing. You jsut specify several annotations and everything is magically serialized / deserialized. Read about gson [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Again sorry that this is not exact answer of the question, but still I hope it will help you get started in json.